# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute Python

Tags: python, tkinter, figure

I dont know why i get this error and it's really annoying... anyone see the problem?
I get this error:

```
 line 66, in <module>
    ting.movefigure(ting, "up", 20)
    AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'movefigure'
```

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import * import time


def movefigure(self, direction, ammount):
    x = 0
    y = 0
    ammount2 = 0

    if direction == "up":
        print("Direction = " + ammount)
        y = ammount
    elif direction == "down":
        print("Direction = " + ammount)
        ammount2 = ammount - (ammount * 2)
        y = ammount2
    elif direction == "right" + ammount:
        print("Direction = " + ammount)
        x = ammount
    elif direction == "left":
        print("Direction = " + ammount)
        ammount2 = ammount - (ammount * 2)
        y = ammount2
    canvas.move(self, x, y)


root = Tk()

root.title('Canvas')

tingx = 100 
tingy = 100

tingxMove = 1 
tingyMove = 1

canvas = Canvas(root, width=400, height=400) 
ting = canvas.create_rectangle(205, 10, tingx, tingy, tags="Ting", outline='black', fill='gray50')

canvas.pack()

ting.movefigure(ting, "up", 20) 
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: how does ting related to movefigure. movefigure is separate method doesnt belong to ting

Comment: I thought when you did that it will take the first object(ting) as the self in the args?
how do i have to do it then?

Comment: just remove ting. and run movefigure(ting, "up", 20)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up functions and methods.

A method is a function defined in a class; it takes a `self` argument, and you call it on an instance of that class. Like this:

```
class Spam(object):
    def __init__(self, eggs):
        self.eggs = eggs
    def method(self, beans):
        return self.eggs + beans

spam = Spam(20)
print(spam.method(10))
```

This will print out `30`.

---

But your `movefigure` is not a method of any class, it's just a regular function. That means it doesn't take a `self` parameter, and you don't call it with dot syntax. (Of course there's nothing *stopping* you from calling any parameter `self` if you want, just like there's nothing stopping you from writing a function called `print_with_color` that erases a file named `/kernel`, but it's not a good idea…)

---

So, you wanted to do this:

```
def movefigure(rect, direction, ammount):
    # all of your existing code, but using rect instead of self

movefigure(ting, "up", 20)
```